# plot contours in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I plot contours ?

I have x, y, z. I wish to plot contour lines using V values.

```
# data
tbl <- tibble(x = runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 1),
              y = runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 1),
              V = x^2.5 + y^2)

# plots
ggplot(data = tbl, 
       aes(x = x,
           y = y
           z = V)) + 
  geom_contour_filled(alpha = 0.8, breaks = seq(0, 2, 0.2)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way, solving the problem with a shameless copy&paste of the `franke` example in the documentation of [`geom_contour_filled`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_contour.html).

The trick is to use package `interp` to prepare the data for plotting. In the code below the only change in the instruction to create `grid` is the data set being binned.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(tidyverse)
  library(interp)
})

set.seed(2022)
tbl <- tibble(x = runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 1),
              y = runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 1),
              V = x^2.5 + y^2)
grid <- with(tbl, interp::interp(x, y, V))
griddf <- subset(data.frame(x = rep(grid$x, nrow(grid$z)),
                            y = rep(grid$y, each = ncol(grid$z)),
                            z = as.numeric(grid$z)),
                 !is.na(z))

# plots
ggplot(data = griddf,
       aes(x = x,
           y = y,
           z = z)) + 
  stat_contour_filled(alpha = 0.8, breaks = seq(0, 2, 0.2)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

## Edit

To better control the bins, use either argument `bins` or argument `binwidth` instead of `breaks`. The following code has a bin width of `0.1`, doubling the number of bins and now uses `geom_contour_filled`, like in the question.

```r
ggplot(data = griddf,
       aes(x = x,
           y = y,
           z = z)) + 
  geom_contour_filled(alpha = 0.8, binwidth = 0.1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. May I know how can I control the grid size in interp

Comment: @SiH You can control the grid size in the plot, see the edit. In `inter`, set arguments `nx` and `ny` to values other than the default 40.

Comment: Thank you sir, is there an alternative to interp. For some reason, I am unable to install it.

Comment: @SiH Try package `akima`. And why are you unable to install `interp`, what is the error message?